# Passing data to new ViewController through Segue

Tags: ios, json, swift, segue, jsondecoder

I am trying to pass a string of data through a segue. The JSON data has been parsed using JSONDecoder and appears properly in the console. Everything is working fine except for when I try to pass the data to a details ViewController I either receive no data or an error. I am using `prepareForSegue` to pass the data.

Here is the code for the ViewController:

```
var nowPlaying = [Results]()
var searchTitle = [Results]()

struct NowPlaying: Codable {
    let results: [Results]
}

struct Results: Codable {
    let title: String
    let poster_path: String?
    let id: Int
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var films: [Results]

    if searchBar.text == "" {
        films = [nowPlaying[indexPath.row]]
    }

    print("\(films)")

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailsSegue", sender: films)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailsSegue" {
        if let detailView = segue.destination as? DetailsView {
                let filmCell = sender as? Results
                detailView.filmId = filmCell!.id
                print("\(filmCell!.id)")
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error at the `detailView.filmId = filmCell.id`

> Cannot assign value of type 'Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

This is what prints to the console for `print("\(films)")`:

```
[Film_Bee.FilmsViewController.Results(title: "Venom", poster_path: 
Optional("/2uNW4WbgBXL25BAbXGLnLqX71Sw.jpg"), id: 335983)]
```

Nothing prints for `print("\(filmCell!.id)")`

I'm not sure why it's not finding the id within the results if its being found when parsed and when the cell is selected.

Here is my code from DetailsView:

```
class DetailsView: UIViewController {

let homepage = FilmsViewController()

var filmId = 0

var filmDetails = [Details]()

struct Results: Codable {
    let title: String
    let poster_path: String?
    let id: Int
}

struct Details: Codable {
    let title: String
    let poster_path: String
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(filmId)

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define

```
var films: [Results]
```

and then call

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailsSegue", sender: films)
```

and then cast

```
let filmCell = sender as? Results
```

which will not work since `Results` is not `[Results]`, decide if you want an array of `Result`s or just one.

Comment: if I try `let filmCell = sender as? [Results]` I get the error `Value of type '[FilmsViewController.Results]' has no member id` on the next line.

Comment: @JSharpp which is true since an array has no `id` property, only individual films have, **decive what you want: an array or an instance**.

Comment: Ok, so I change `var films: [Results]` to `var films: Results`. That works, thanks!

Comment: @JSharpp there you go :) probably with the changed assignment of `films = [nowPlaying[indexPath.row]]` => `films = nowPlaying[indexPath.row]` !?

Comment: Yeah and the same for the next line. Probably should have added that in there.

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider your singular/plural naming. You want to pass **one** film, not an array

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let film : Results // singular form `Result` is less confusing

    if searchBar.text.isEmpty {
        film = nowPlaying[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        film = searchTitle[indexPath.row]
    }

    print("\(film)")

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailsSegue", sender: film)

}
```